# What will happen if i subscribe multiple times a channel with single pubnub instance?

Tags: android, pubnub

If i have subscribed a channel multiple times with single pubnub instance whether it will subscribe,if it subscribes which callback will be executed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## PubNub Subscribe connectCallback behavior

When you subscribe to a channel successfully, `connectCallback` will be called.

Every time you call `subscribe` to a different channels after that, the `connectCallback` will be called.

But if you subscribe to a channel that you are already subscribed to, then `connectCallback` will not get called (essentially no-op).

[Sample Java/Android `subscribe` code](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java-se-java/api-reference#subscribe):

```java
pubnub.subscribe("my_channel", new Callback() {
 
          @Override
          public void connectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
              System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : CONNECT on channel:" + channel
                         + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                         + message.toString());
          }
     
          @Override
          public void disconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
              System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : DISCONNECT on channel:" + channel
                         + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                         + message.toString());
          }
     
          public void reconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
              System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : RECONNECT on channel:" + channel
                         + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                         + message.toString());
          }
     
          @Override
          public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
              System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : "
                         + message.getClass() + " : " + message.toString());
          }
     
          @Override
          public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
              System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : ERROR on channel " + channel
                         + " : " + error.toString());
          }
      }
);
```